# jQuery Ajax-load replaces page instead of div in IE9 (without developer tool mode-switching)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm working on a website where one of the pages has a list of articles and an option to filter these based on certain keywords. All the keywords are links and listed to the right of the list. In order to get the correct URL's, the links on each keywords hold part of the ajaxURL that would give the correct response for the given keyword. In addition, I got a script that adds a 'click'-event to all links and appends the last required parameters to the ajaxURL. I "reload" the list by using jQuery's 'load'-function, like this:

```
$('a.keyword').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    // Other logic

    $('.list').load(ajaxURL);
}
```

However, when using the filter in IE9 the content of 'ajaxURL' is loaded into the entire page. That is, the entire page is replaced with the resulting list. I figured this could be a problem of only using 'event.preventDefault()' on the 'click'-event I got on each link, so I added a variety of alternatives:

```
event.stopPropagtion()
return false
if(event.preventDefault){
    event.preventDefault();
} else {
    event.returnValue = false;
}
```

After hours of debugging, trying different combinations of these and trying IE7, IE8 and IE9 using the developer tool provided in IE, I realized that the first time I open the page with IE9 (without opening the developer tool), I get the problem described above. However, when I open the developer tool and selects IE8 it all works perfectly! The same happens when I change it back to IE9! (In this case I used all the alternatives above.)

For some reason, these transitions make it work! I can't figure out how to fix this.. I can't force users to open developer tool and switch mode to make i work. :P Any ideas? Does the developer tool add something that could do this?

I appreciate any help on the matter! :-)

**PS.** It works just fine in Chrome, ++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is having `console.log()` in your script. That statement throws a Javascript error in IE up until you open the Developer Tools.

If that occurs earlier than the code you provided in the question then the rest of your script probably won't get evaluated, and your event handlers won't be bound at all, causing the links to just be regular links.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I wish I could upvote more than once.